# Nginx doesnt work

Tags: nginx

In ubuntu 12.04 (server):

```
sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev zlib1g-dev
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.5.6.tar.gz && tar zxvf nginx-1.5.6.tar.gz && cd nginx-1.5.6 && ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Then I try:

```
sudo service nginx start
or
nginx -s reload
```

and many others that I find in google - all of them doesnt works. (nginx: unrecognized service, no command found, etc)

How to start nginx?

Comment: what is the output of `which -a nginx`? And what do you mean by `Does not work`?

Comment: @Eternal-Learner `which -a nginx` - no output. Does not work means error messages - (nginx: unrecognized service, no command found, etc

Comment: check `/opt` if nginx is being installed there

Comment: @Eternal-Learner nothing in this dir

Comment: so that means your source compilation is failing. Instead of concatinating all the commands together, try running them one by one. This way, you will notice which step is failing. You can add a `--prefix` to the `./configure` command to force installation in a particular folder (`/opt/` is the convention)

Comment: why don't you use `sudo apt-get install nginx` ?

Comment: @erdimeola i want use new version. I try to use commands one by one -  no error and failings.

Comment: reinstall with `--prefix=/opt` or use `find` to locate where you are installing it. Once you find it, add it to your `$PATH`. That should solve your problem. Next time, please post all the information you have while asking a question. Some basic self-research does not harm either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install nginx like you installed those libraries. The only reason to compile it manually is if you want a really new feature or security fix.

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

It should automatically start nginx. If not you may start it manually.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

Answer (score 6):

for you guys, who used nginx installation via passenger:

```
$ wget -O init-deb.sh https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rschmitty/5891885/raw/9b737a42e950581f16ed3074c69f5bcb920f24cb/660-init-deb.sh
$ sudo mv init-deb.sh /etc/init.d/nginx 
$ sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/nginx 
$ sudo /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f nginx defaults
```

It enables standard service nginx start|stop|restart|reload commands

Comment: I didnt use passenger. Mine was just built from source. But I forgot about making my init script executable... It's been a long day. Ha.